# Regular triangulation of hypercube

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, triangulations, hypercube

I have started studying regular subdivisions of the $n$-cube, and came across the following post: [Regularity of Delaunay triangulation of a hypercube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130878/regularity-of-delaunay-triangulation-of-a-hypercube).

My question is whether the "standard triangulation" of the $n$-cube described in the answer of that post is always regular. I know that the answer is yes in two and three dimensions, and, intuitively, I would guess that it is also true for arbitrary $n$. I'd be grateful for any help.

(A subdivision is regular if it can be obtained by lifting the vertices to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and projecting the lower faces of the convex hull of the lifted vertices to $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: More generally the canonical triangulation of the order polytope of any poset (with simplices corresponding to linear extensions) is regular. But this question seems a little too low-level for this site.

Comment: See pp. 439-440 of https://www.csun.edu/~ctoth/Handbook/chap16.pdf.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you! I‘m new to this topic, and wasn‘t aware that it’s that simple.